# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows error

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am writing a method that finds outliers and print them to the user alongside a special symbol that indicates the outlier type. The outliers could be calculated in two ways: the Engineer's method or Tukey's method. The function takes two parameters: a data frame with one column of random numbers and option value that determines the method to be used in calculating the outliers. The function will return a data frame with two columns the value of the outlier and its type as a symbol (o or *)

When I call the function and I ask it to calculate the outliers using the engineer's method it works perfectly. However, using the Tukey's method it generates the following error (data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows)

The following is my code:

```
findOutliers<- function(numbers,option){
outlierM=c()
outlierE=c()
outlier=c()
typeM=c()
typeE=c()
type=c()
length=nrow(numbers)
print(numbers)


if(option=="eng"){
print("Engineer Methods")
numbersmean= as.numeric(sapply(numbers,mean)) 
numbersd= as.numeric(sapply(numbers,sd))


for(i in 1:length){
zscore= as.numeric((i-numbersmean)/numbersd)
if(zscore>2 & zscore<3){
#cat(zscore," ", "O","\n")
outlierM =c(outlierM,zscore)
typeM=c(typeM, "O")
}#end of if statment

else if(zscore>3){
#cat(zscore," ", "*", "\n")
outlierE =c(outlierE,zscore)
typeE=c(typeE, "*")


}#end of if statment

}#end of for loop
}#end of if statment


else if(option=="tukey"){
print("Tuckey's Methods")
sortedNumbers=numbers[order(numbers$Numbers), ]
IQR=IQR(sortedNumbers)
Q1=as.numeric(quantile(sortedNumbers,0.25))
Q3=as.numeric(quantile(sortedNumbers,0.75))
rangeM1=Q1 - (1.5 * IQR)
rangeM2=Q3 + (1.5 * IQR)
rangeE1=Q1 - (3 * IQR)
rangeE2=Q3 + (3 * IQR)

for(i in 1:length){
if(numbers[i,]<rangeM1|numbers[i,]>rangeM2){
outlierM=c(outlierM,numbers[i])
typeM=c(typeM, "O")
}#end of if statment

else if(numbers[i,]<rangeE1|numbers[i,]>rangeE2){
outlierE=c(outlierE, numbers[i])
typeE=c(typeE, "*")}

}# end of for loop 
}#end of if statment



outlier= c(outlierM,outlierE)
type=c(typeM,typeE)
founOtliers<- data.frame(Outliers=outlier,Type=type)
return(founOtliers)

}#end of function

normalnumbers=rnorm(10)
randomNumbers<- data.frame(Numbers=normalnumbers)
findOutliers(randomNumbers,"eng")
findOutliers(randomNumbers,"tukey")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things.  First, I suggest indenting your code and using spaces where possible for clarity.

```
if (x = 1) {
  print ('foo')
} else {
  print ('bar')
}
```

Second, and more importantly, you are using the if/else syntax incorrectly (see my example above).  From `?"if"`:

```
In particular, you should not have a newline between ‘}’ and
     ‘else’ to avoid a syntax error in entering a ‘if ... else’
```

---

However, that is not the problem, per say, in your code.  If you add the lines

```
print (paste('first check', 
             numbers[i, ] < rangeM1 | numbers[i, ] > rangeM2))
print (paste('second check', 
             numbers[i, ] < rangeE1 | numbers[i, ] > rangeE2))
```

at the top of your second `for` loop, you'll see that you never satify either `if` condition, thus you return your empty `data.frame`...

In general, if you're using the `if` `else if` syntax, I think it is wise to always include a final `else` catchall that can provide some helpful advice or a default output.